# Portreserve not starting starting portreserve: (not starting, no services registered)

Tags: nfs

while start the portreserve service i am getting below error.Please tel me suggestion

starting portreserve: (not starting, no services registered)

Comment: which flavour of linux you are trying to start/install? Kindly include more info what you tried etc.. Kindly update the question.

Comment: rhel6 in aws instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solved solved the issue after created the /etc/portreserve/spamd file with 783 value.
cat /etc/portreserve/spamd
783
but i don't know what is the issue.if knows anybody please explain..